# SQL help to display no. of openings for all branches for each month of a year

Tags: sql, grouping

Hi I need to generate a SSRS report to show how many centers got opened for each month in a calendar year under each branch. report will have 13 columns, first column being all the branches in each row and remaining 12 columns will have months of an year as header. I'm trying to get a result of each branch having no. of openings per month, so I can feed SSRS to display in tabular format. If a branch doesnt have any openings for any month, I need to display 0.

```
Branch table
=============
Branchid
Branchname

CenterOpen table
================
CenterOpenID
BranchID
CenterOpenDate
```

below is the SQL I had written

```
WITH months(MonthNumber) AS (
  SELECT
    1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    MonthNumber + 1
  FROM
    months
  WHERE
    MonthNumber < 12
),
cteBranch(BranchID, BranchName, TargetOpenDate, Month, Count) as (
  SELECT
    B.BranchID,
    B.BranchName,
    CS.TargetOpenDate,
    MONTH(CS.TargetOpenDate) as Month,
    count(Month(CS.TargetOpenDate)) as Count
  FROM
    Branch B
    left join goal.CenterOpenSchedule CS ON CS.BranchID = B.BranchID
  GROUP BY
    B.BranchID,
    B.BranchName,
    CS.TargetOpenDate,
    MONTH(CS.TargetOpenDate)
)
select
  *
from
  months
  cross join cteBranch
order by
  BranchID asc,
  MonthNumber asc
```

If I use cross join, months are repeating for each branch, how to resolve this? your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample input and output, and your actual output

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which database you are on.
There are different ways to extract month/year from date.
Based on your example SQL, I'm going to use MONTH()

```
select branchName, 
count(case when month(centerOpenDate) = 1 then branchId end) Jan_Count
...
...
count(case when month(centerOpenDate) = 12 then branchId end) Dec_Count
from Branch b
join CenterOpen co
on (b.BranchId = co.BranchId)
where year(centerOpenDate) = <your year filter>
group by branchName
```

This will take care of your below requirements:

" first column being all the branches in each row and remaining 12 columns will have months of an year as header."

and also -

"If a branch doesnt have any openings for any month, I need to display 0."

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not explicit, but you seem to want a single year -- so you need to filter on the year.

The rest is basically conditional aggregation:

```
select b.branchName, 
       sum(case when month(co.centerOpenDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when month(co.centerOpenDate) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as feb,
     . . .
       sum(case when month(co.centerOpenDate) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as dec
from Branch b join
     CenterOpen co
     on b.BranchId = co.BranchId
where year(co.centerOpenDate) = @year
group by b.branchName
```